# Otherwise idle SQL Server slamming disk for database with no connections

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server Express 2014, at times I will notice in Resource Monitor that `C:\...\SqlServer\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\[DatabaseName]_log.ldf` and the corresponding `[DatabaseName].mdf` are being read at 16MB/sec and 5MB/sec each.

Within SQL Server Management Studio, if I run the Activity Monitor, there are no connections using that database.  No queries on other databases are active.

I do not have AutoShrink turned on.

The database should be idle.  What could be causing it? How can I turn it off?

Comment: Have you verified that the IO activity is coming from the SQL Server process(es) and not something else like a malware scanner or external backup solution?

Comment: 16MB/sec isn't exactly what I would call "*slamming disk*" but yes it is a little odd if you have no active connections / queries, that you're seeing the database files come up at all. Agreed with David, or alternatively wondering if some other internal SQL Server process (maybe something required for Express Edition such as Telemetry) is running occasionally.

Comment: Antivirus software scanning the files?

Comment: AutoClose turned ON (express edition default)

Comment: @DavidSpillett I should have mentioned, Resource Monitor is explicitly attributing the disk activity for those two files to `sqlservr.exe`. @JD Yes, I was a little overly dramatic. :) If there is another process within SQL Server Express, is there some way of querying to know what is going on? @TiborKaraszi There is antivirus, but its file activity is usually noted under its own process or the generic "System". @Igor AutoClose is turned ON. I turned it off, I'll see if that changes anything. Thank you all for your ideas!